# Geopandas map projection upside down

Tags: coordinate-system, geopandas

I'm trying to create a choropleth map of the US counties using Geopandas, but for some reason, the map is plotting upside down. I'm guessing it has something to do with the projection embedded in the json file, but I'm very new to spatial data visualization.

Can you help me understand why this might be happening?

I downloaded the json from this site: https://github.com/topojson/us-atlas

```
import geopandas as gpd
us_counties_url = 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/us-atlas@3/counties-albers-10m.json'
us_counties = gpd.read_file(us_counties_url)
us_counties.set_crs(4326, allow_override=True)
us_counties.plot()
```

[image: upside down plot]

Comment: it does not have crs, however, the crs is not ```4326```. ```epsg:4326``` is latlong, so between -180 to +180. your coordinate is between 0 - 1000, so you are setting the wrong projection. Plus the data is just bad, you need to process it like, flip it out.